# How to sort rows in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'domaci2');
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM utisci';
        $result = $link->query($query);
        while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $link->query('SELECT pk FROM utisci ORDER BY ocena DESC');
        }
        $result->free();
        mysqli_close($link);
```

It is very simple, i am just trying to sort my table but it is not working. 
Extra info:

- pk variable is the primary key of table
- ocena variable is integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do `SELECT pk FROM utisci ORDER BY ocena DESC` in the body of the `while` loop. Do it before the `while` loop instead of `SELECT * FROM utisci`.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. If you provide more detail, I might be able to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: well thats is whole code. Only task it has to do is to sort table when i press link. I have to links, one sorts in ASC order and other in DESC order

Comment: You have to do something like `echo $row['pk'];` in the body of the while loop to actually see the output.

Comment: You are right. It is sorted, but only in the code while table stays the same.

Comment: Database tables cannot be sorted. Database tables are [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). The result set of a query can be sorted, even by the database itself. But this does not affect the tables that are involved in the query.

Comment: Thanks for info. Obviously i was trying to do something that was imposible

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'domaci2');
$query = 'SELECT pk FROM utisci ORDER BY ocena DESC';
$result = $link->query($query);
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
   // what you want to do with $row
}
$result->free();
mysqli_close($link);
```